# How to display image in pdf using html-string in flutter iOS app?

Tags: css, flutter, dart, pdf-generation, dart-html

**Edit: I have posted the answer for Android but still unknown about iOS case.**

How to create the circular image using html-string in flutter? 
**src="assets/test.jpg"** OR **src="file:///assets/profyl.jpg"** is not working.

Here's what I have:

```
Future<void> _printPdfAsHtml() async {
  print('Print ...');
  await Printing.layoutPdf(onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) async {
    return await Printing.convertHtml(
        format: format,
        html:
            '<html><body><table><tr><td><img src="assets/test.jpg" alt="Avatar"></td><td>Purple</td></tr></table></body></html>');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This work for android case** *but not for iOS*.

```
<img src="file:///android_asset/flutter_assets/assets/profyl.jpg" alt="Avatar" height="100" width="100 style="border-radius: 50%;">
```

Comment: Did you eventually figure it out for iOS? I'm having the same issue now.

Comment: Not till now !!

Answer (score 1):

***Answer when the Question was:*** *How to add circular-image using html string in Flutter? Image not displaying*

1. Have you added your Image to the Asset Section in the `pubspec.yaml` (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images)
2. If yes: Can you access it in the Flutter Code using `Image.asset('path/yourimage.png'),`
3. Try to use the ImageProvider like in the Example here: https://pub.dev/packages/printing#-readme-tab- *(You will not be able to use HTLM then)*

---

***Answer when the Question was:*** *How to add circular-image using html string in Flutter*

You can use the `border-radius: 50%` property on your Image.

In your case the following should work: `'<html><body><table><tr><td><img src="assets/profyl.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="border-radius: 50%;"></td><td>Purple</td></tr></table></body></html>'`

See this example here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_images.asp

Or the reference here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

Comment: Image is not displaying. So, is the reason behind this?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? So your Image is not even showing up in your pdf export? This is not mentioned in your question. **EDIT** OK you added it now with Edit Nr. 6